# How do I replace information that isn't being pulled (and therefore blank) with other information (HTML)?

Tags: html, if-statement, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid to build email templates for clients. I have created an invoice template which has a bill to and a ship to address, and this information is pulled from our database to fill in those sections on the invoice.
However, not all of our customers will have ship to addresses, and currently on the template this section is being left blank.
If there is no ship to address in our database, I want to replace it with the bill to address so that there are no empty spaces on the invoice.
What can I write into the HTML so that, when there is no ship to, it duplicates the bill to address?

```
            <table style="width: 150%;"> 
        <tr> 
    <td style="text-align: left;">  Bill To <tr> <td style="text-align: left;"> 
            {{header.addr_blk_num1_stmt}}
            {{header.addr_blk_num2_stmt}}
           {{header.addr_blk_num3_stmt}}
            {{header.addr_blk_num4_stmt}}
            {{header.addr_blk_num5_stmt}}
           {{header.addr_blk_num6_stmt}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
             <td style="text-align: right;">
            <p style="line-height: 2em; vertical-align: top;">
              <em>Ship To</em>
              <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">
            <p style="line-height: 1.5em; vertical-align: top;">
              {{header.shipto_firm}}
              {{header.shipto_address_1}}
              {{header.shipto_city}}
              {{header.shipto_state_code}}
              {{header.shipto_zip}}
              {{header.shipto_country}}
              </td>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```